How to Install ROS2 Packages on Windows 10
In the past, I worked with Ubuntu-Ros1. When transitioning to Ros2, I initially wanted to try it on Windows. I installed Ros2 Humble on Windows 10 as a binary and have managed to run basic nodes. However, I started encountering issues when it came to working with packages. A similar question was asked in the link provided here, but the link in the response is currently not working. Additionally, what I'm really curious about is whether packages created for Humble-Ubuntu might not work on Humble-Windows. For example, Nav2 installation does not mention Windows. Even installing such a widely used package on Windows seems impossible or difficult. So, is it possible that many of the developed packages cannot work on Windows? If so, would it be accurate to say that ROS2 natively works on Windows? And in this case, could using ROS2 on Windows be considered a waste of time? My question might be a bit complicated, and I appreciate your help.

Did you report the broken link?
